# If the sum of everywhere linearly independent vector fields are periodic, are the component vector fields periodic?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

I feel like the above must be true but embarrassingly cannot seem to prove it. Take linearly independent, commuting vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on a manifold and corresponding flows $\Phi^t_X$, $\Phi^t_Y$. Suppose that the diffeo associated flow $t\rightarrow \Phi^t_X \circ \Phi^t_Y$ is the identity for some $t_1>0$. Does it follow that $\Phi^{t_1}_X= \Phi^{t_1}_Y=\text{Id}$? What if $X$ or $Y$ vanish at some isolated points? Does the "result" (which is not currently a result) still hold?

Comment: If we are on the flat torus $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$ and your vector fields are constant, aren't you just asking whether the fact that the sum of 2 linearly independent vectors has integer coordinates implies that each of them has integer coordinates? I presume it does not, but, perhaps, I misunderstand the setup?

Comment: I think in the specific case that the vector fields are on torus and constant (by constant I assume you mean invariant wrt to the Lie group structure on the torus), then maybe the question reduces to what you said, though I am not quite sure what you mean by "integer coordinates". Of course the v.f. could have whatever coordinates as long as the ratio is rational.

Comment: I mean take two translation flows $\Phi_a(x)=x+at$ and $\Phi_b(x)=x+bt$ on $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$ with the usual Euclidean metric. At time $1$ the composition shift is $a+b$. If it is in $\mathbb Z^2$, it is the identity on the torus.

Comment: Ok, I understand but I am not quite sure how this answers the question.  On the torus with these v.f. it seems to be true but I don't easily see how to generalize to other cases.

Comment: I guess that the  answer is  positive in the 2 torus  case. the  first observation is that if  $X$ possess at least  one  $t$-periodic orbit, then all orbits of $X$ are $t$-periodic. Because the  commutativity of  flows  and  linear indepent property implies $X$ has no an isolated periodic orbit. On the other hand every vector field without closed orbit on the torus is  topological equivalent to  some  kronecker foliation which all orbits are dense.According to the comment  of @fedja  I think that two independent $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}$ can not sum up to an element of $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Comment: If $X=(1,\epsilon)$ and $Y=(1,-\epsilon)$ then the sum will have a periodic orbit on the standard torus $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$ for $t=\frac12$, but the fields $X$ and $Y$ will not.

Comment: @MikhailKatz, ah yes of course how silly of me. I only just understood the point of fedja . If someone wants to write this up as an answer I will accept, otherwise I will do so myself :)